# in spring jpa : can i use define class as @Embeddable and still use it as bean?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

i have a question related to spring beans and JPA

i have one Entity A 
which has Embeddable class B as one of the parameters. B has Embeddable class C as one of its parameters.

**my question is**: can i use C both as embeddable class and as spring bean? for example. can i do something like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "game/nextQuestion/answer/{userAnswer}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public final Question answer(
        @PathVariable("userAnswer") final Long userAnswer,
        @RequestBody final QuestionDetails details,
        @ModelAttribute("game") GameObject game, Model m)
        throws GameNotFoundException {

    return model.answer(userAnswer, game, m,details);
}
```

in the above example QuestionDetails is the "C" class that's embedded in "B" which is embedded in "A"
and Question is the "A" class

thanks!

oak

Answer (score 0):

Simply, yes you can. This is normal POJO class. Special usage is only when this class is persisted.